# How to center a container horizontally without centering the text inside the container?

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

**Issue 1**: How can I centre the container `div` horizontally while `Typography` remains at left?

*Desired result:*

[image]

**Issue 2**: How to put any component below the `AppBar` automatically without using `margin-top` or `transform: translate`?

Here the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-bpskw?file=/src/components/what_is_covid/about.module.css

Comment: Your link is only showing the navbar

Comment: @NicoShultz cause it's the home page and the text is hidden under the AppBar ,i didn't  apply margin-top

Comment: You can toggle to different components by clicking the `menu icon` on the top

Answer (score 0):

1: How can I centre the container div horizontally while Typography remains at left?

remove `align-items: center;` from `._src_components_what_is_covid_about_module__container` and add the following

```
._src_components_what_is_covid_about_module__container {
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

2. How to put any component below the `AppBar` automatically without using `margin-top` or `transform: translate`?

You are not going to get this without a margin top I've fixed it like this on all pages.

```
.App {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

The only problem here is that you `navbar` doesn't have a fixed height so if it gets higher that 100px the content will still be underneath it

Comment: I've added it to your styles.css can you see that?

Comment: is there any way to fix the navbar !

Comment: What is wroing with it?

Comment: you can't make any change with my code, so fork it and share the link of your codesandbox code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-drawer-sijk0?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: you will have to give your container a specific width smaller than body and set its margin: 0 auto; And after that, you could do whatever you want inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform that by using **FLEXBOX** alignment

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-top: 100px; */
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.containerText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

and in the `about` Component wrap the `Typography` component in a div with `containerText` class like this

```
<div className={styles.containerText}>
    <Typography
        align="left"
        varient="h4"
        color="secondary"
        style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}
    >
        What is COVID-19?
    </Typography>
</div>
```